# Apache Storm TICK tuple equivalent in apache flink?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-storm

I'm new to apache Flink. I want to log count of entries in my cache  every hour to a file.I did this in storm using tick tuple. Does Flink have something similar which i can use in a flink operator?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [ProcessFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/process_function.html), which can be used with both process time and event time timers. But I'd say that Flink's [window operator](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/windows.html) is the most natural way to count things in time-bounded windows.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try both.